# How can I model the curvy side of a motorcycle body cover?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I have to model this bike, any tips for those curves on the side?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the general shape without caring about the slits:

[image]

Pull the vertices to give it the 3D shape:

[image]

Cut the slits with the knife:

[image]

Push the vertices to dig the shape:

[image]

You'll need to bevel some edges to keep them sharp:

[image]